# Segregating data into columns after reading data from excel

Tags: r, excel

I have data in excel in the form

```
 SessionIDSourceIPDestinationIP
 206192.67.36.714182.79.86.214
 206191.73.38.756182.89.86.214
```

By applying **text to Document** in excel I am able to seperate the data as

```
 Session ID     Source IP       Destination IP
   206        192.67.36.714       182.79.86.214
   206        191.73.38.756       182.89.86.214
```

In R trying to read the data as above but i am not able to seperate the columns as above.

How can I do it??

Comment: Is your data *in* Excel, or is it in another file and you want to figure out how to read it correctly? If you are able to read it in Excel, you could always save the file as a CSV and read that into R very easily.

Comment: Then did you try `read.csv("name-of-your-file.csv")`?

Comment: yes , but the data is coming out to be in 206/192.67.36.174/182.79.86.214 format

Comment: What's your actual delimiter then? It would help if you actually posted a couple of lines of the actual CSV file (open it in a text editor and paste that output as part of your question).

Comment: @user235467 If the answer(s) worked for you should upvote and/or accept the answer(s). If not you can update your question or respond to the answer(s) why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read it with `read.fwf` which allows you to specify the column widths.

```
df <- read.fwf("youcsvfile.csv", widths=c(3,13,13),skip = 2)
colnames(df) <- c("Session ID","Source IP","Destination IP")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the source data are laid out (Are there always 3.2.2.3 digits in the IP numbers?) you may want to use a regular expression to split the data:

```
# Load your data without the header line:
x=read.csv('mydata.txt', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)

# set up regex to capture groups. 
# (Being a bit conservative in case of three digits in middle values.)
rex='^(\\d{3})(.+\\.\\d{3})(\\d{3}\\..+)$'

# Extract data to get subset of each captured match
df <- data.frame(SessionID=gsub(rex,"\\1",x$V1), SourceIP=gsub(rex,"\\2",x$V1),DestinationIP=gsub(rex,"\\3",x$V1))
```